# How to render content from backend in templates?

Tags: typo3

I am going to try to explain my problem is specific as possible.

Created a typoscript file called Portal.ts in the BackendLayouts folder, added several rows and columns. Added a Portal.html in the correct folder and made a layout in the Layouts folder which uses a  to render the Portal.html template. (Which is where I make all the magic happen)

Now, what I want to do is add content in the backend. So what I did is create a page called Portal. Then went to appearance and selected the Portal layout. Saved, and it seems to work. Great!

Now I add some content, to the columns using the backend. My question now is, how can I retrieve that content in the templates? I made a header, images and text.

This is my Portal.ts:

```
backend_layout {
    colCount = 2
    rowCount = 2
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = Hoofdteksten
                    colspan = 2
                    colPos = 1
                }
             }
        }

        2 {
             columns {
                 1 {
                     name = Afbeeldingen
                     colspan = 3
                     colPos = 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the template file:

```
<f:layout name="Portal" />
<f:section name="content">

    <div id="portal"> RENDER HEADER FROM BACKEND HERE </div>

</f:section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set variables in your `FLUIDTEMPLATE` object in TypoScript. Something like:

```
page = PAGE
page.1 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.1 {
    templateName = Basic2ColumnPage
    templateRootPaths.1 = fileadmin/sitedesign/Resources/Private/Layouts
    variables {
        contentNormal < styles.content.get
        contentRight < styles.content.get
        contentRight.select.where = colPos = 2
    }
}
```

`styles.content.get` is used to get the content. By default it will fetch the content from the current page with `colPos = 0`, so if you want to fetch from a different column you add `select.where = colPos = 2` (where 2 is the column you want to fetch it from). You can then use the variables in your template.

For more on this, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TemplatingTutorial/BasicFluidTemplates/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need a global TypoScript configuration for rendering content. This could look like follow:

```
lib.content {
    render = CONTENT
    render {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            orderBy = sorting
            where.cObject = COA
            where.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    field = colPos
                    intval = 1
                    ifEmpty = 0
                    noTrimWrap = | AND colPos=||
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have something like this in you project, you can use it in your fluid templates with the help of the `cObject` VieHelper like this:

```
<div id="header">
  <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content.render" data="{colPos:1}" />
</div>
```

I desribed this in detail in a blog post at https://usetypo3.com/backend-layouts.html

Comment: to avoid such complicated cObjects you should use the marker for select: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select.html#markers

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I disagree, no one should ever use markers. It looks so chaotic

Comment: from documentation: `Each value is properly escaped and quoted to prevent SQL injection problems. This provides a way to safely use external data (e.g. database fields, GET/POST parameters) in a query.` and do you really argue that `where = AND colPos=###colPos###` is more chaotic? ;)